# FIxing google contacts display fields

Tags: android, android-contacts, google-workspace

I use gsuite and android. Ever since using an international LG phone, they have save names a bit weird.

If I make a contact called 
F:Mat
L:Johnson

Then it looks fine on android. When I open https://www.google.com/contacts/ the user would be displayed as JohnsonMat. If I click the ... it will still have the F:Mat
L:Johnson

It's just somehow the display name is backwards and no space.

Now I have about 500 contacts saved from my phone over time and I can't use gmail because it can't find users by F:Mat. The only way to get a name to pop up is to start to type JohnsonM. Firstly I can't remember last names, secondly if I have 20 Johnsons I can't skip them.

Is there some way to fix these via some script?

Comment: try changing phones.

Comment: Thanks. That's very useful, but I've already had the LG G3, G4, G6 do this. So while it's probably something with LG, I don't have the cash to keep buying lots of phones. Although the original LG nexus 5 was fine.

Also there's the 500 existing contacts that need to be fixed no matter what.